# Dynamic Package.json version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, versioning, auto-update

I have an electron app and I'm using the auto updater on it. Now, I'm trying to create update channels. (Like beta, alpha, live etc.) To be able to do this, I have to use different package versions(Like V0.0.1-beta, V0.0.1-alpha, V0.0.1) but, I couldn't create a dynamic package version. Is it possible to create a dynamic version number like the following? If it is possible, how can I create it?

```
"version": "$REACT_APP_ENV_UPDATE_CHANNEL_STRING", (Value from environment variables.)
```

or

```
"version": "V0.0.1${environment_tag}", (Value from environment variables.)
```

I'm trying to create this format because after creating a package for the first environment, I'm planning to handle the next versions via GitHub Actions and environment variables.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need a script that generates the file for you

Comment: Do you have a similar sample? Or how can I search it?